# Posting nested JSON to WordPress Admin Ajax - can't access object data

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to mock a payload my WordPress webhook will be receiving once an integration is setup. The payload will contain nested JSON. I've not been able to access data in the JSON object in my PHP function.

This is the structure of the payload I can expect:

```json
data: {
  attributes: {
    user_name: "John Doe",
    user_email: "johndoe@xyz.com"
  }
}
```

Here's my JavaScript that's attempting to POST the same data:

```js
fetch(wp_ajax.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        action: 'course_signup',
        data: {
            attributes: {
                user_name: "John Doe",
                user_email: "johndoe@xyz.com"
            }
        }
    })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here's my PHP:

```php
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_course_signup', 'course_signup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_course_signup', 'course_signup');

function course_signup()
{   
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    $user_name = $data['attributes']['user_name'];
    $user_email = $data['attributes']['user_email'];

    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo json_encode(array(
        "action" => $_POST["action"],
        "user_name" => $user_name,
        "user_email" => $user_email
    ));

    die();
}
```

Here's the response of my `console.log(response))`:

```json
{
   action: "course_signup",
   user_email: null,
   user_name: null
}
```

In the Network tab for the POST request I see the payload as:

```json
action: course_signup
data:  [object Object]
```

Comment: If you see `[object Object]` in the network panel, that probably means the data got messed up before you send it already.

Comment: `json_decode($_POST['data'])` - why? The value that you sent was an object, and you serialized it via `URLSearchParams`. So at what point did you expect this to turn into JSON ...?

Comment: `json_decode($data, true)` for an associative array result

Comment: Yes, https://jsfiddle.net/p7gq4y9d/ confirms that your data is messed up before you send it already. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams#parameters: _"A record of string keys and string values. **Note that nesting is not supported.**"_

Comment: _"I'm trying to mock a payload my WordPress webhook will be receiving once an integration is setup."_ - instead of writing your own code for such purposes, perhaps check out https://www.postman.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CBroe,

Using Postman helped simplify this.

I updated my PHP to the following which allowed me to access the data I wanted:

```php
$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$user_name = $payload['data']['attributes']['user_name'];
$user_email = $payload['data']['attributes']['user_email'];
```